# How to get a form field to auto fill when a product is entered?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get my form to populate the days needed for testing automatically when I enter a new record but it keeps erring out. I am very new to using VBA and Access 2016.

I have looked at some other examples that people have posted that work and cannot get it to work.
I am continually getting debugger.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Fill_SKU_AfterUpdate()
    PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()
    frmSerialTracerLog.Days_Used_For_Off_Test = DLookup("Days_Used_For_Off_Test", "tblTestDays", "Fill_SKU = '" & frmSerialTracerLog.Fill_SKU & "'")
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of control is `Days_Used_For_Off_Test`? The controls themselves are Access Objects, so if you're trying to actually change the control, you would need a `Set` statement. If you're trying to change the value of a textbox, you would use `Days_Used_For_Off_Test.Value`. (You probably have a similar issue with `Fill_SKU`)

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 2):

You probably are referring to the current form, thus use *Me*:

```
Private Sub PopulateFields()
    Me!Days_Used_For_Off_Test.Value = DLookup("Days_Used_For_Off_Test", "tblTestDays", "Fill_SKU = " & Me!Fill_SKU.Value & "")
End Sub
```

Comment: If the sub is located in the module for the form, isn't the `Me!` also un-necessary?

Comment: Probably yes, but the use of Me makes it clear what the intention with the code and the ownership of the control are.

Comment: I tried this and now I get a data type mismatch in criteria expression. I checked and the fields I am referencing are all "Number" type. Is there something in the form that would throw it off?

Comment: No, but if number, no quotes. See edited answer, please.